# store username/password within an iphoneapp using keychain

Tags: ios6

I have a registration form in which there are so many fields and i am saving all the field's data in the form of json data on the server which is entered by a new user.
In all these fields i have two fields username and password.I want to store these in keychain 
and i use the following code for this:

```
[[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];

[keychainItem setObject:@"passtextfield.text" forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychainItem setObject:@"usernametextfield.text" forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
```

So whenever a new user will submit their registration form then username and password will be saved in keychain with the keys respectively.

Now my question is that- i have an other login page and when I have to start the app as an user, i have to login first with username and password entered by me as an user at the time of registration.

Now tell me the code that how can i login and retrieve the keychain data.
and should i do any change in the (accessGroup:nil) i have used above.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The accessgroup is not server side, it is iPhone side. From the docs:

> Access groups can be used to share keychain items among two or more applications. For applications to share a keychain item, the applications must have a common access group listed in their keychain-access-groups entitlement, and the application adding the shared item to the keychain must specify this shared access-group name as the value for this key in the dictionary passed to the SecItemAdd function.

If you have two login pages your app logic will need to store two user/password combinations. So you'll want to point  `kSecAttrAccount` towards the currently active account.

-- Edit

From your comment I understand you want something like the password-remember-function in Safari?

So you have Username1/password1 and username2/password2. Username"x" is your `kSecAttrAccount`.

When the user enter the username use `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. in `textFieldDidEndEditing` scan the entered string for a match on either `username1` or `username2`. If there is any match then retrieve the corresponding password. If there is no match then assume it is a new username/password combination and store this new one, too.

If you want to get fancy and scan for a match while they type, then read up on `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Comment: "I have only one login page. The username/passwords are stored through registration page which is different not a login page.But now when i entered the username and password in the login page (and plz note that i have been done my registration some time or somedays before)i want to check both from the keychain that they exixts or not.tell me how?